# Read string from plc using moka7

Tags: java, plc, snap7

How to read string from PLC from DB560 with offset 0.0 and size 12 bytes. Garbage value is coming at the output.

```
S7Client client = new S7Client();
client.SetConnectionType (S7.S7_BASIC);
int res = client.ConnectTo("192.168.0.1", 0, 1); 
byte[] data = new byte[12];
client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB, 560, 0, 12, data); 
String ret = S7.GetStringAt(data,0,12);
System.out.println(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 bytes of the **S7 data type string** are as follows:

Positon n: Maximum length
Postion n+1: Current length

Because of this the first character is not  at position n but at positon n+2.

```
byte[] data = new byte[14];
client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB, 560, 0, 14, data);
String ret = S7.GetStringAt(data,0+2,12);
```

Alternative:

```
byte[] data = new byte[12];
client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB, 560, 2, 12, data);
String ret = S7.GetStringAt(data,0,12);
```

Or you change the moka7 code to something like this (this is the code of sharp7):

```
public static string GetStringAt(byte[] Buffer, int Pos)
{
    int size = (int)Buffer[Pos + 1]; //Current length of the string
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer, Pos + 2, size);
}
```